# Remove a patch that was created with yarn

Tags: react-native, node-modules, yarnpkg, patch

Since `@shoutem/ui` had a limitation with `ref` param I added a patch for it to respect the ref implementation by adding `ref={(input) => this.props.inputRef(input)}` to:

[image: @shoute/ui TextView path].

The team ended up not using this path and created a different approach to solve the issue. I would like to roll back this patch. I couldn't find a way to remove the patch, as easy as it is to add it. I have checked [documentataion](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch) but couldn't find the detail about it.

I have also tried:

```
yarn patch-package package-name --reverse
```

Check `--reverse` under **Options** heading, at the documentation here https://yarnpkg.com/package/patch-package.

Ex.: `yarn patch-package @shoutem/ui --reverese`

Even after that when I run `yarn install` I see that in my patch list (check image) which I want to get rid of.

[image: --reverse test]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete that patch file from the patches folder?
if not then:

1. Find the patches folder in your project as shown in the below image
   [image]
2. Select the patch file which is not required and delete it.
3. Run **Yarn install**

**It worked for me like a charm. Happy coding**

I hope answered your question well.